# How to join ResultSet objects in java?

Tags: java, oracle

I have two   connections .

```
Connection cone = ... // to DB2
Statement statement = cone.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet1 = statement.executeQuery("select * from tableone");

Connection ctwo = ... // to Teradata
Statement statement = ctwo .createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet2 = statement.executeQuery("select * from tabletwo");
```

How can I join these two tables ?

---

so far i am writing the above result sets to csv using opencsv API . And then manipulate the two csv files . I am sure my approach is far from ideal , it takes time and not efficient

**There must be an efficient solution . After all , the two  result sets are java objects . There must be a way of joining them without third party API**

Comment: I read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228036/joining-multiple-result-set but did not get any solution

Comment: Can you describe your scenario in the post?

Comment: I have updated my question with the sample code

Comment: If both result sets map to the same entity, it should be really trivial to get both in the same collection.

Comment: What collection type do you mean ? hash map

Comment: What is the regular way people do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a temporary table in DB2 as it was mentioned , might not be the best way . Simply due to permission restrictions . The question asks clearly , how to join two result set objects.

I believe there was an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290363/how-to-combine-two-resultsets-in-java) on Stackoveflow

```
while (rs1.next) {
    YourClass obj = new YourClass();
    obj.setSomeProperty(rs.getString(1));
    obj.setAnotherProperty(rs.getString(2));
    // etc..
    cominbedDataSet.add(obj);
}
```

good luck

Comment: I believe you understood the question wrong.. This is the question: "How can I join these two tables?"

Answer (score 2):

If both schemas are consistent, you may create the same object for each row of both `ResultSet`s and them put all of them in a single `List`.

For example,

```
List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();
while(resultSet1.next()) {
    // retrieve fields here...
    results.add(new T(...fields...));
}

while(resultSet2.next()) {
    // retrieve fields here...
    results.add(new T(...fields...));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to load your results from Teradata into a temp table in DB2 and perform the join after.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JoinRowSet class that you may use.

```
// Data from one table
ResultSet someTable = con
         .createStatement()
         .executeQuery("SELECT id FROM some_table");

CachedRowSet someTableCached = new CachedRowSetImpl();
someTableCached.populate(someTable);

// Data from another table
ResultSet otherTable = con
         .createStatement()
         .executeQuery("SELECT id, man_id FROM other_table");

CachedRowSet otherTableCached = new CachedRowSetImpl();
otherTableCached.populate(someTable);


// Joining them
JoinRowSet jrs = new JoinRowSetImpl();
jrs.addRowSet(someTableCached, "id");
jrs.addRowSet(otherTableCached, "man_id");
```

More details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/joinrowset.html