# how to merge two different resultsets from two different DBs in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I have two resultsets, one from DB2 and one from Sybase.
I want to merge these resultsets based on some condition,for which i have made one function which will take two resultsets and merge them.

But i am getting SQL exception- **Resultset Closed**

I am using Connection object and Prepared statement to connect to the respective DB and execute the query.

```
public void ExecuteDB2Query(SQLQuery){
Connection DB2con = DB2Sess.connection();
PreparedStatement statement = DB2con.prepareStatement(SQLQuery);
MyResulset1= statement.executeQuery();
}
```

Another method:

```
public void ExecuteSybaseQuery(SQLQuery){
Connection Sybasecon = SybaseSess.connection();
PreparedStatement statement = Sybasecon.prepareStatement(SQLQuery);
MyResulset2= statement.executeQuery();
}
```

Final merge method

```
puble void merge{
while(MyResultset1.next()){
while(MyResultset2.next()){
<some code here>
}
```

Do we have any way by which i can loop through these two result sets? without any exception.

Comment: make your connection scrollable and reset to first your resultset2 on each iteration.

Comment: how can i make my connection scrollable?

Comment: prepareStatement(SQLQuery,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE); and Sybasecon.prepareStatement(SQLQuery,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE); it allow you to move forward & backward as well as move your cursor to first or last upon resultset function call.

Comment: I am so sorry but i am not getting your point.

Comment: can you please tell me in the context of what i have given above in my code. Like:-                                          public void ExecuteSybaseQuery(SQLQuery){
Connection Sybasecon = SybaseSess.connection();
PreparedStatement statement = Sybasecon.prepareStatement(SQLQuery);
MyResulset2= statement.executeQuery();
} Here in this method where i have to make changes?

Comment: i have written your code with modification that i want to share with you. Please check. One more thing how would you pass your two result set to merge function ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to loop through those two result sets with a nested loop. That can't be done, since after the inner loop finished its first iteration, `MyResultset2` cannot be used anymore.

I suggest you iterate over the two result sets separately and store their data in some Collections. Then you can iterate over those Collections however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i'll give you your code check it.

```
public void ExecuteDB2Query(SQLQuery){
  Connection DB2con = DB2Sess.connection();
  PreparedStatement statement = DB2con.prepareStatement(SQLQuery,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
  myResulset1 = statement.executeQuery();
}


public void ExecuteSybaseQuery(SQLQuery){
  Connection Sybasecon = SybaseSess.connection();
  PreparedStatement statement = Sybasecon.prepareStatement(SQLQuery,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
  myResulset2 = statement.executeQuery();
}

public void merge{
  while(myResultset1.next()){
    myResultset2.first();
    while(myResultset2.next()){
      <some code here>
    }
  }
}
```

make changes in this code according to your requirement.

Comment: also checkout this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368107/how-to-join-resultset-objects-in-java

Comment: i am getting exception in this

Comment: what exception your are getting?

Comment: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: Invalid argument: Statement auto-generated keys value 1004 is invalid.
            at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.p.a(p.java:3851)
            at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.p.a(p.java:2118)
            at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.p.prepareStatement(p.java:2194)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
            at org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:50)
            at $Proxy6.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
`

Comment: in which method this exception occurring. I thing it is in merge method. Is it so?

Comment: No this exception is coming in ExecuteDB2Query method even before executing the query. Exception occurs after PreparedStatement statement = DB2con.prepareStatement(SQLQuery,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE); line.  TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE is coming as 0